# google charts using ado.connection in php my db is mssql

Tags: php, sql-server, google-visualization

can anyone help me how to run this code in php. i copy google chart code then add while condition to display my query. but nothing happen when run this code.

```
<?php
    include("includes/mssqlconn.php");
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['AgentName', 'Transaction', 'Amount'],                       

    <?php                                                                                           
        $conn->open($connStr); //Open the connection to the database
        $conn->CommandTimeout = 1000;

        //declare the SQL statement that will query the database                    
        $query =   "select top 10 a.Account
                    ,COUNT(txn) as TxnCount
                    ,sum([amountloc]) as Amount

                    from table  a

                    where (Dateloc between '20170201' and '20170205')

                    group by  a.Account
                    order by TxnCount desc";

        $rs = $conn->execute($query);

        while (!$rs->EOF)  //carry on looping through while there are records
            {
        ?>      
          ['<?php echo $rs->Fields["a.account"]->Value;?>', '<?php echo $rs->Fields["txncount"]->Value;?>', '<?php echo $rs->Fields["amount"]->Value;?>'],

          ]);

        <?php

            $rs->MoveNext();
            }
            $rs->Close();
            $conn->Close();

            $rs = null;
            $conn = null;
        ?>

        var options = {
          title: 'Performance',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

my connection is ado.connection and I am using MSSQL 2008.  any help will do.

Answer (score 0):

i found my error. just replace above code to this.

```
while (!$rs->EOF)  //carry on looping through while there are records
                {
            ?>      
              ['<?php echo $rs->Fields["a.account"]->Value;?>', '<?php echo $rs->Fields["txncount"]->Value;?>', '<?php echo $rs->Fields["amount"]->Value;?>'],



            <?php
                $rs->MoveNext();
                }
              ?>
                  ]); //the problem is here
            <?php
                $rs->Close();
                $conn->Close();

                $rs = null;
                $conn = null;
            ?>
```